# Sublime Spintax Syntax Highlighting

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

Can anyone help me improve my regex for my 'spintax' syntax highlighting in sublime?

It's working but it's really slow to load, I think because my regex is being too greedy. This is only 4 level of spintax depth tho, going beyond that will make it load longer.

Maybe I'm putting the sublime syntax all wrong, but is there a way to make it faster and go infinite depth?

`main:
    - match: '({{0,1}[^{}]*?)({{0,1}[^{}]*?){[^{}]*}([^{}]*}{0,1})([^{}]*}{0,1})'
      captures:
        4: variable.language
        3: keyword
        2: keyword
        1: variable.language
        0: string`

Spintext example:

[image]

Comment: It is slow because you are using lazy quantifiers where greedy ones should work the same. `({?[^{}]*)({?[^{}]*){[^{}]*}([^{}]*}?)([^{}]*}?)` should be a bit faster. However, you cannot use recursion (to go infinite depth) if you need the captured values.

Comment: Thanks for your input @WiktorStribiżew I had assume lazy is better in performance than greedy, or isn't? Anyway, I had made a little improve to the capturing, `({?[^{}]*({?[^{}]*({?[^{}]*({[^{}]*})[^{}]*}?)[^{}]*}?)[^{}]*}?)` which gives me cleaner matches but at this depth, it's still giving me few minutes load time. I hope someone have some more insights for this.